Investigate why packages are held back, and stop release upgrade
I have a System76 computer that came with Ubuntu, but I installed xfce4 on it, and made other changes so that it is now effectively Xubuntu.  It has been performing very well, but will now not upgrade from Focal to Jammy.  It complains:
  fwupd-signed gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap ubuntu-software

I have tried solutions from other questions that involved apt --upgrade-only, but they did not help.  The rest were hard to follow, and I was not sure that trying them would be safe, so I'm doing this as a new question.
The first question probably should be: do I need gnome-software and ubuntu-software when I'm using lightdm and xfce?

After reading answer 1, I made some changes and retried.  It failed like so...
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeApport.py", line 49, in apport_crash
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 495, in <module>
    def get_process_environ(proc_pid_fd: int) -> dict[str, str]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1991, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.calcDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5218svyf/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1100, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
AttributeError: 'DistUpgradeController' object has no attribute 'tasks'
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sat Sep  7 18:27:32 2024) ===


It seems to have gotten as far as processing triggers. Now what?
Being advised that my original question was answered, I opened a new one to investigate why I get a crash when I try to update.  See Why does do-release-upgrade fail with an error on Xubuntu 20.04.6 -> 22.04?

My recommendation is, backup data in your home folder and fresh install Ubuntu 24.04. If you want XFCE, then fresh install Xubuntu 24.04 instead. Since you have multiple desktop environments, the upgrade might mess up the GUI.

You probably would not believe the complications that hinder trying bring a fresh install up-to-date.  all kinds of .rc files, special scripts for root as well as home.  I've been tailoring my Ubuntu's from my grad school days around 1995-2002, and this particular machine since June 2016.  I really really want to upgrade.  And I don't use multiple environments, though they might be installed.  Just xfce.

You can remove these software and then perform the upgrade. In any case, please be aware that upgrades go wrong (too many people faced error during 22.04 -> 24.04 upgrade recently. 20.04 -> 22.04 does not have such issues though). You should always have a backup of your .rc files and scripts so that you can get them back in no time.

I have backups of all partitions (partclone is handy for that), that were taken yesterday.  And it's not just .rc files -- they are just an example.  Scripts for managing projects.  Lots of other directories, partitions and mount points.  There are about 14 partitions and one 32 TB RAID5 partition on 3 18TB drives.

FYI:   The system I'm using now has Xubuntu Desktop (Xfce), Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME), Lubuntu Desktop (LXQt) and more installed.. Today I logged in with the Lubuntu/LXQt session so I'm using LXQt, last selected choice was Ubuntu/GNOME..  but having multiple flavor/desktops installed shouldn't impact anything in my opinion...  Your issue is something else..


Do I need gnome-software and ubuntu-software when I'm using lightdm and xfce?

Not at all. GNOME Software is a front end for APT/snaps to install/remove software with a GUI. Ubuntu Software is a frontend of snaps (i.e. snap store). You can always use command line APT/snap for installing software.
You can remove these software and perform the upgrade. If you want, you can reinstall these software after the upgrade.

My question really was what do gnome-software and ubuntu-software actually contain.  How do I even find that out?  Will I need any of that while I'm doing the upgrade?

@ForDummies I updated my answer with information about their purpose

Thanks.  I took a look at them in synaptic.  Ubuntu-software was marked as transitional with the advice that it could be removed.  So I did.  The others are marked oddly, including gnome-software as "broken".  I'll remove them, upgrade and see about re-installing.  Thanks for your info, it at least gives me something to try, and the backups make it safe.

Odd: I could not remove them unless I also installed libxmlb2.  It is not clear why, but it worked.  Now we'll see how the upgrade goes....

This got a lot done, but ended with an error. The report is too big for a comment, so I put it in the question.

@ForDummies That is a different error. Please ask a new question (I don't know the answer to this, but I am sure someone will know), and roll back this quetsion to its previous state. I answered the original question about gnome software.
